# Pass binary to Oracle stored procedure using varchar2 in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have an Oracle Stored Procedure to calculate a checksum of a data block:

```
CalculateCheckSum( datablock in varchar2, result in out varchar2)
```

I have another C# procedure to get a 100 bytes data block and then call the stored procedure:

```
main()
{
  string r;
  byte[] data = new byte[100];
  /* put something into data[] */
  r = getCheckSum(data, "/*a connect string*/");
}


string getCheckSum(byte[] data, string ConnStr)
{
  string result;
  string datablock;
  using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnStr))
  {
    conn.Open();
    datablock = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "CalculateCheckSum";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("datablock", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, datablock, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 8, "00000000", ParameterDirection.InputOutput);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    result = cmd.Parameters["result"].Value.ToString();
    conn.Close();
  }
  return (result);
}
```

I found that everything is OK if all the bytes of the data[] has value less than 128. Otherwise, the stored procedure will find that the length of datablock is more than 100.

Can anyone solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

An UTF8 Char needs 1-4 byte to store and the length of a varchar2 is given in byte by default.
Chars with a value between 0 and 127 can be stored in one byte, chars with higher values need more bytes to store.
But you can set the lenght of a varchar2 in number of chars when you want.

```
VARCHAR2(1)       lenght 1 byte 
VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)  lenght 1 byte
VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)  lenght 1 char > 1-4 byte
```